# Datamax DLP Send and print an image above other text using python

Tags: python

Does anyone have any experience with the DLP Language?

Im trying to use python to send some text and barcodes and now i need to send a bmp image to.

The documentation is really hard for me to read so i was hoping others have used before and can help me.

Here is the documentation
https://www.honeywellaidc.com/en/-/media/en/files-public/technical-publications/printers/1common/dpl_88-2360-01_b.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible. Here is how I am doing it at the moment, on a Datamax O'Neil printer installed on Windows. The DPL command below can be sent to the printer using the [win32print wrapper for python](https://pypi.org/project/win32printing/), or sent directly to the printer's IP using the [socket library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html):

**DPL code:**

```
dpl_code = b'''<STX>LH15D11FA+
191100200140035THIS IS SOME TEXT
1W1j00050010000THIS IS A CODE128 BARCODE
121100000850010
1Y1100501600315THIS_IS_AN_IMAGE_FILE_ALREADY_STORED_ON_THE_PRINTER
191100202650010THIS IS SOME MORE TEXT
E'''
```

The < STX > must be replaced by a special character (value: 0x02 by default, which doesn't render as text). Each line represents either a string of text, or a graphical component like a barcode or image pre-stored in the printer's memory. for more details on the language syntax, refer to the [DPL command reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj-8ZmdqJjxAhXPct8KHXA5AdEQFjAAegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.honeywellaidc.com%2Fen%2F-%2Fmedia%2Fen%2Ffiles-public%2Ftechnical-publications%2Fprinters%2Fpc43-pc43-pc23%2FDPL-EN-CR.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2jmw1Qk5OmzLX_BdSWrady).

**For a printer installed as the default printer on Windows:**

```
import win32print

printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
printer = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)
win32print.StartDocPrinter(printer, 1, ("raw_data", None, "RAW"))
win32print.WritePrinter(printer, dpl_code)
win32print.EndDocPrinter(printer)
win32print.ClosePrinter(printer)
```

**For a printer accessible via network:**

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as connection:
  connection.settimeout(timeout)
  connection.connect((ip_address, port))
  connection.send(dpl_code)
  response = connection.recv(1024)
```

This method is somewhat successful for me, but I found it much easier to work with Zebra printers (ZPL). As for sending images and printing them, I have not yet been successful unfortunately. I need to first pre-store an image in the printer's memory (as a BMP file) using the [NetiraCT software](https://honeywellaidc.force.com/supportppr/s/article/Where-to-find-NetiraCT-configuration-utility) and refer to it with the DPL code.